# Unable to Download Sitecore 8 even when certified

Tags: sitecore

I am a certified sitecore developer and would like to download the new Sitecore 8 to practice.

I go to this [Page](https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Sitecore_Experience_Platform/8_0/Sitecore_Experience_Platform_80_Update5.aspx) and enter the credentials.

When clicked on 'Sitecore web application installer' OR 'ZIP archive of the Sitecore site root', nothing happens. It just reloads the page.

Is the download option available at all. If not, are there any other ways to practice get a hands on this CMS

**UPDATE:**

When I click on the download links, it says *Sorry – you do not have permission to download this file. If you are already Sitecore certified, please log in.*

I have logged in already and both these pages show

https://portal.sitecore.net/
https://profile.sitecore.net/Profile.aspx

> Website .NET Developer Certification for Sitecore XP 8.0, INT
> International TC

Is this a bug.

Comment: That's exactly what you should do. Then Sitecore Download License popup should be displayed and download should start. Do you have any js issue? Have you tried other browser?

Comment: Another and more convenient way of trying is to download directly from Sitecore Instance Manager.... but again, if you have permissions for your SDN account.

Comment: I have SIM 1.3.0.700 and it has option to install an instance from a file saved locally. Could you please tell me how to download a file from online

Comment: Are you certified Sitecore 8 developer? Sitecore 8 downloads are only available when you have S8 certification.

Comment: Ofcourse I am. I have mentioned the exact text that is displayed in my SDN account above

Answer (score 2):

The issue is indicated by the error message, you don't have the appropriate permissions.

I have had this issue in the past. I got in touch with Sitecore and they fixed the issue on their side.

Comment: Indeed,. Reach out to sitecore and, assuming you've gone through the WND training, they'll be able to enable the permissions.

Comment: Hi Jason, I'm having the same issue... How exactly did you contact sitecore? I find only sales email in contact section. thanks

Comment: I believe webmaster@sitecore.net is the correct address.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same issue, so I reached out training@sitecore.net to solve it.
They replied that it might take up to 72 hours to get your accounts synchronized.